# Check in error "We can't do that becuase the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted"

Tags: document-library, excel, check-out, check-in

SharePoint 2013, Office 2013 Std 32 bit. Win7 Pro 64bit Sp1.

I've got an issue with checking my .XLSX file back in after any edits.

Error message is as follows:

> "We can't do that because the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted"

It's still there and no one else uses the file but me.

This is a new development since I've been fine for months now until last week.
We've rebooted everything, cleared all sorts of cache (via CCleaner for example) and the issue persists.  I also must add that a few different problems have surfaced as well. Example, I cannot add a new item in a "custom list" as I'm greeted with "**This content cannot be displayed in a frame**".. I can "**Open this content in a new window**" but even that's not foolproof here (meaning it could still error later)

One potential issue:  IE10 was accidentally installed on this machine (my laptop, we block via Group Policy) likely working from home one day.  I've since uninstalled it, reinstalled IE9 with all related security patches but I CANNOT say for certain when this issue started because we don't now when IE10 showed up..... I'm not seeing any other web page related errors anywhere but SharePoint at this time.

Comment: Can try hitting f12 and setting the browser mode to IE9 and see if that helps to determine if it is an IE10 issue.

Comment: Thx Eric, just tried both IE9 and IE9compat mode. Same issue.

Comment: @user20121: Did you ever figure this out? This started happening to me recently, seemingly after some Windows Updates.

Comment: What happens when you view the document from Site Settings<Content and Structure? You may be able to override whatever check in it seems to believe is going on. Good luck!

Comment: For anyone getting this in SharePoint Designer for a file, make sure you're checking the right radio button option. If you accidentally checked in a minor edit last time and usually do a major edit, the bottom option will be 'overwrite the current _minor_ version' but normally it is 'overwrite the current _major_ version', for example, and just selecting that radio button out of muscle memory will result in this error--to fix you'd need to select the middle radio button 'check in major version' instead, and then you can revert to the 3rd radio button again for subsequent major updates.

Answer (score 2):

From the description it looks like you are having trouble with the document properties when you try to check in the document. This may be caused by a change in the Content Type and/or Site Column related to the document. Most likely a required field was added, or a field was changed to be required which wasn't before.

It's not unusual to have these issues in the development phase and my suggestion is to change the document type of your document to be the default document type.

Then remove the document type from the library (settings) and add the document type again. When this is done, edit your document to the "new" document type once more, and see if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur due to the presence of disallowed characters, such as **/**, in the file title.

To resolve this problem, it is recommended to modify the file title by avoiding the use of any special characters.

> Check the detailed steps at [We can’t do that for you because the file
> is no longer checked out or has been deleted in SharePoint
> Designer](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-file-is-no-longer-checked-out-or-has-been-deleted/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, most of the solutions in the web did not work, but luckily, there was a hint in the error message which helped to resolve. It is to do with the Metadata/column. When I created a column of multiple options, I accidentally selected "Unique" value option as Yes. When I disable this, then it works as charm!